# C++ to C# code conversion

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to emulate some C++ code in C#. I am not familiar with the intricate workings of C++ and don't quite understand how to implement this code in C#.

Could someone please explain what the functions are doing and what their output would be in ASCII? In particular, I do not understand what the "memcpy" method is doing the way this code is written.

```
//example values
str = "<Request Type="Query" Version="1.0"></Request>"
uintcrc = getCrc(str, strlen(str));

//code i don't understand

//create a byte array with a null terminator?
memset(strQueryBuffer, '\0', sizeof(str));
//print the values into the byte array
sprintf(strQueryBuffer, "%c%s%c", COMM_STX, str, COMM_ETX);

//append the uintcrc to the end of the byte array?
memcpy(strQueryBuffer + strlen(strQueryBuffer), &uintcrc, sizeof(uintcrc));
```

Comment: How much you pay me?

Comment: This isn't C++ code, this is C. In any case, don't. You're better off looking at what you want to do and finding the C# way to do it. This "emulation" business is just bad.

Comment: As @Borgleader mentioned, emulating is just bad.  It's like translating a language word-for-word in your native language which doesn't always work out.  You need to understand what the method is trying to accomplish and do it using methods available in C#.

Comment: Please don't built something that looks like XML with string.Concat/strcpy/...

Comment: When you run that bit of code, what output do you get?    If you can describe what it does then you can more easily recreate it (properly) in C#, than simply guessing by looking at a few lines of code.   if you can't see any output directly, run it in your debugger and inspect `strQueryBuffer`

Answer (score 4):

it does nothing else than

```
 strQueryBuffer = COMM_STX + "<Request Type='Query' Version="1.0"></Request>" + COMM_ETX + Encoding.Ascii.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(uintcrc));
```

if you have a binary system and want to send the complete information binary, you can also write

```
 var str = "<Request Type='Query' Version="1.0"></Request>";
 byte[] Data = (new [] { COMM_STX }).Concat(Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes(str)).Concat(new [] { COMM_ETX }).Concat(BitConverter.GetBytes(uintcrc)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I believe it's the other way round -- a byte array is being built, not a string.

Comment: ok could also be that the system just works binary, so i added a version for that

Answer (score 0):

```
strQueryBuffer + strlen(strQueryBuffer)
```

is same as

```
&strQueryBuffer[strlen(strQueryBuffer)]
```

so it append binary value of crc to the end of strQueryBuffer